# Github's gist endpoint is not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gist

I would like to access my public gists through javascript, but the following code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/binroot/gists';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        document.write(data[0].description);                                           
    });
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a [same-origin policy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). The GitHub API [supports JSONP](http://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks), so you can use that. jQuery picks up on `callback=?` in your URL and will automatically use JSONP.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/binroot/gists?callback=?', function(data) {
    // do whatever as before, but note that your data
    // will now be in a property called "data" with the
    // header information in "meta"
});
```

Comment: John, would a request to https://gist.github.com/raw/3849235/5fb40674a675c550d251d4d8f1bb73cd9375617f/thinkpad.quote also require a callback?

Answer (score 0):

You can not request resource from different origin with JavaScript because of the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), for more about gist api, please checkout this:http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/